# Нужно ли делать сослагательное наклонение?

Tags: стилистика

Простите, мне как "бы", так сослагательное. Может, у частицы совсем иная роль?

> Я не предложу вам ничего из того, что сама не попробовала и не
>   полюбила.

Почему-то напрашивается частица "бы", но, может, и без неё всё прекрасно?

*Я не предложу вам ничего из того, **что** (чего?) сама не попробовала бы и не полюбила.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Я не предложу вам ничего из того, что сама не попробовала и не полюбила.* Нормальное сложноподчинённое предложение с местоимённо-определительным придаточным. Вот винительный падеж союзного слова  на родительный при отрицании я бы заменила.

Насчёт сослагательности полностью согласна с Александром: здесь она неуместна и возможна только  в **разговорном стиле** для добавления обусловленной возможности, и то частица БЫ тогда стояла бы скорее после союзного слова:

*Я не предложу вам ничего из того, чего бы  сама не попробовала и не полюбила.*

Разговорность, а  то и просторечность конструкции создаётся видо-временной несоотнесённостью.

В книжных же стилях нормой употребления сослагательного наклонения глагола является его использование в придаточных **условных**, о чём можно прочитать в статье по Вашей ссылке.

Если вносить сослагательность в местоимённо-определительное, то нужно вносить её в обе части:

*Я не предложила бы вам ничего из того, чего бы сама не попробовала и не полюбила.*

Comment: Люсенька, помогите! "Есть ли тут стилистическая ошибка? Какая?" - https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435920/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F/435933#435933 СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 2):

Без неё всё прекрасно. Добавление не будет ошибкой, но добавит неуверенности высказыванию, будет эквивалентом оговорки (мол, если где-то что-то, то разве что редактор попутает или меня вдруг занесёт). В обещании на будущее или в предисловии это нежелательно, хотя извинительно в высказывании о прошлом (может, и были грешки, о которых не помню - не проверяла, как издано на самом деле).

И ещё сослагательность при будущем может быть оправдана в случае, если "предложение" отсрочено во времени (сначала поживу там годик, потом предложу из своего прошлого и ближайшего будущего - что бы в нём ни нашлось для вас полезного из того, что полюбится, будучи попробованным).

Comment: БЫ: употребляется при образовании сослагательного наклонения (в сочетании с глаголами в форме прошедшего времени) ◆ *Было бы несправедливо сказать, что природа обидела Ивана Акиндиныча Бергамотова, в своей официальной части именовавшегося «городовой бляха № 20», а в неофициальной — попросту «Баргамот».*  Л. Н. Андреев, «Баргамот и Гараська», 1898 г. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%8B

Comment: Сослагательное наклонение здесь возможно для выражения допущений (в принципе может так оказаться, но я не такая, чтобы предлагать чего не попробовала **бы** напр. _между обещанием и предложением_ - чего пока ещё не было).