# "Три и больше номеров..." - напомните, пожалуйста, правило!

Tags: согласование

> Нумерация домов в Риме таит немало неожиданностей. Возможно, она и
>   подчиняется каким-то закономерностям, но мне они неизвестны. Крошечный
>   домик с единственной дверкой может нести на себе три и больше номеров,
>   а протяжённый многоэтажный дом – только один.

Помнится, что "номеров" должно согласоваться с "три"; дайте, пожалуйста, ссылочку на правило.

Спасибо!

Comment: Не верится в согласование с тремя: три и более номеров = три и более (трёх) номеров. Подразумеваемое должно влиять.

Comment: Саша, читайте ответ "университетки" Людмилы! Со ссылочкой!

Comment: Типичное циркулярное насилие над языком! Вариант с перестановкой (три номера и более) - совершенно другой, он не может приводиться в качестве аргумента.

Comment: *В сочетаниях два (три, четыре) и более… управляемое существительное ставится в родительном падеже  е д и н с т в е н н о г о  числа: два и более варианта, три и более трудных формы, четыре и более ценных предложения, т. е. существительное ставится в зависимость от числительных два, три, четыре, а не от слова более (ср. возможность перестановки: два варианта и более).*  http://2yxa.ru/rus/styli_xxxviii_164.wml ; http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xxxviii.html

Comment: Лучше бы запретили порядок слов, сеющий смуту :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если считать больше = более,то правило таково:

6. В сочетаниях два (три, четыре) и более… управляемое существительное ставится в родительном падеже единственного числа: два и более варианта, три и более трудных формы, четыре и более ценных предложения, т. е. существительное ставится в зависимость от числительных два, три, четыре, а не от слова более (ср. возможность перестановки: два варианта и более).
   https://megalektsii.ru/s37104t1.html

Comment: Спасибо, милая Люсенька! А где мне пятёрка за умнейший  вопрос?! ))) Загляните, пожалуйста, и сюда: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435914/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/435919?noredirect=1#comment443874_435919