# Есть ли тут стилистическая ошибка? Какая?

Tags: стилистика

> В магазинах продавцы из вредности начнут ползать как мухи, пока их
>   основной состав расположился за долгим обедом на площади.

Это кратенько; вопрос к слову "расположился" (время глагола).

Расширенный контекст, если не очень понятно:

> Рим живёт в режиме пансионата. День его расписан по часам. Активная
>   фаза начинается с рассветом и длится до полудня. В 12:00 закроется
>   большинство церквей (некоторые из них побогаче, чем собрания наших
>   музеев!). **В магазинах продавцы из вредности начнут ползать как мухи,
>   пока их основной состав расположился за долгим обедом на площади.** В
>   12:30 открывается приличная кухня. Но важно не опоздать. Последний
>   заказ – в 14:00. С этого момента в вашем распоряжении останутся только
>   супермаркеты...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasmin права, здесь нарушена видо-временная соотнесённость глагольных форм.

В 12:00 **закроется** большинство церквей (некоторые из них побогаче, чем собрания наших музеев!). В магазинах продавцы из вредности **начнут** ползать как мухи, пока их основной состав **будет располагаться** за долгим обедом (будет занят долгим обедом) на площади. В 12:30 **откроется** приличная кухня ( **откроется - закроется** - антитеза, тоже должно быть полное соотнесение по виду и времени). Я бы ещё поставила рядом "располагаться" и "на площади" (где располагаться?), а уж потом что они там делают - "за долгим обедом".

Comment: Всё принято! И главное - минимальное вмешательство в автора, ведь надо, чтобы он и не заметил правки, думал, что всё так и было! СПАСИБО! )))

Comment: Это точно, авторы-народ обидчивый!

Answer (score 2):

В магазинах продавцы из вредности начнут ползать как мухи, пока их основной состав **будет располагаться** за долгим обедом на площади.

Или –  будет занят долгим обедом на площади.

Действие происходит в одно и то же время, оба глагола несовершенного вида.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы внесла некоторые изменения в текст.
1. "Живет в режиме" — дискомфортно как-то. Возможно, подойдет *живет по правилам* или *существует в режиме.*
2. Между "пансионата" и "день" поставила бы двоеточие.
3. "Фаза начинается" и "начнут ползать" (последнее "начнут" — лишнее).
4. Заменила бы 12:00 на двенадцать.
5. Сделала бы акцент на богатстве церквей весомее (Некоторые из них *богаче*, чем собрания наших музеев!), отдельным предложением.
6. Между "не опоздать" и "последний заказ" поставила бы запятую.
7. Все глаголам — настоящее время.

*Рим живёт по правилам пансионата: день его расписан по часам. Активная фаза начинается с рассветом и длится до полудня. В двенадцать закрывается большинство церквей. (Некоторые из них богаче, чем собрания наших музеев!) В магазинах продавцы из вредности ползают как мухи, пока их основной состав располагается за долгим обедом на площади. В 12:30 открывается приличная кухня. Но важно не опоздать, последний заказ – в 14:00. С этого момента в вашем распоряжении остаются только супермаркеты...*

Comment: Римма Михайлова, но такая правка будет означать, что от авторской стилистики и местами лукавинки и места мокрого не останется. Так с автором нельзя обращаться, его надо холить и лелеять! А если переписывать за ним каждое слово, то а) уже себя срочно понадобиться холить и лелеять и б) понадобится усиленная бригада литературных негров, каждый из которых понятия не имеет, в какую сторону тянет другой...

Comment: * *...себя срочно понадобиться холить и лелеять* - ооо... опечатка:  понадоби***т***ся!